# Generate thumbnail with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I need to generate thumbnail for all images in a folder like this ( example )

Original image:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

I have tried this command

```
mogrify *.jpg -gravity center -thumbnail 350x200 *.jpg
```

What I am getting with this command:

[image]

Platform - Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

A thumbnail is a small version of the graphic.

You seem to want a cropped section of the original, not a thumbnail. So you're using the wrong command. :)

You'll want to use [resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize) the image to one of your desired dimensions, and then use the [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) command(s) to take a copy of the section you want.

Comment: I didn't know that . Can you give me a example pls . I used gnuthumbnailer http://www.gnuyork.org/en/gtn-download.html to create the second image in the question . I have read the crop page . It think the values will change for each image . All the images in my folder are of different sizes .

Answer (score 1):

You want to both crop and resize the image:

```
mogrify -crop 800x520+0+300 -resize 320x200 *.jpg
```

And yes, since you're pictures differ then you may have to adjust the crop parameters per image. With some scripting, you can programatically adjust these parameters however, for example, creating a bash script `cut-resize.sh` as below, and running it with a file name argument, so `cut-resize.sh testimage.jpg`:

```
#!/bin/bash
origX=`identify $1 | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -dx -f1`
origY=`identify $1 | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -dx -f2`
offset=300

eval "mogrify -crop ${origX}x$(($origY/2))+0+$offset -resize 320x200 $1"
```

Will do the nearly the same thing - cut the middle 50% of the image and then resize, for any sized image. You could add additional arguments and variables so you could specify your offset and the ammount to crop, but let your script take care of setting the geometry for imagemagick.

Or on windows, the following batch example *might* work, I have no idea, I only have a linux box, but the point is that you can script adjustment of the variables:

```
file=%1

rem identify %file%  | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -dx -f1
for /f "tokens=3" %%G IN ('identify %file%') DO set temp=%%G
for /f "tokens=1" "delims=x" %%G IN ("%temp%") DO set oldx=%%G
for /f "tokens=2" "delims=x" %%G IN ("%temp%") DO set oldy=%%G

offset=300
newx=%oldx%
newy=%oldy%/2

mogrify -crop %newx%x%newy%+0+%offset% -resize 320x200 %file%
```

A good reference for batch, bash or powershell scripting is http://ss64.com/. Combining scripting with Imagemagick is very powerful once you build out your workflows and scripts.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am on Windows . Will this work in .bat ( from origX till the end ) ?

Comment: Your best bet on windows is to try cygwin to get bash, or use powershell. Scripting with bat files is a PAIN.

Comment: I tried it in cygwin . Named the file resizer.sh . Placed it in D drive in a folder named "a" . Got this very long error http://pastebin.com/i003VgMJ

Comment: try replacing `eval` with `echo` so you can see what command it is trying to run, and adjust. But the scripting was just an example of what you *could* do, the scope of the question is what's the command to crop and resize... scripting is another realm really.

Comment: The Windows script it not working . In your sh code i removed the empty 5th line and the \r error was gone . Now only this is left /2")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Comment: Try 'bash cut-resize.sh' ?

Comment: Same error . What if you perform that origY/2 and stor it in another another variable ?

Comment: Worth a try. It may be time to generate another question re scripting on cygwin. I am past the point where I can be of much use for lack of a windows/cygwin box to test on.

Comment: I don't know how to do it :(

Comment: I put it in another variable . It is working but it is not creating files with 350px . Width is different in every image . Height is 200 in all files .

Comment: Add variables to `-resize` and play with them... now you're coding. Good luck.

Comment: Was this answer helpful at least? If yes or no, please vote accordingly. Thanks.